# How do I check for and reset a timeout atomically?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that checks whether some timeout period has expired, and if it has, resets the start time and returns true:

```
bool CheckAndResetTimeout() {
    if (DateTime.UtcNow > _start + _timeout) {
        _start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I make this thread safe in the sense that if 2 threads hit it at the same time, it is guaranteed to only return true once? I think this can be achieved via double-check locking, but I was hoping to find something in the BCLs (under `System.Threading` most likely) that might provide a higher-level abstraction for this.

Comment: Why don't you use an actual timer? That would handle this internally for you - you'd get a callback when the interval elapses.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because I'd like it to be lazy. The thing calling it is responsible for doing some work if the timeout has expired, and I don't want that work to be done more often then necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The timer just gives you a way to track elapsed time (which is what you do in your example).

Comment: If you want your caller to avoid calling this function more frequently than necessary then your caller should have a timer. You can then have a flag (guarded by a lock) that you can check if work is already going on.

Comment: @xxbbcc I think a solution involving a Timer and [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583.aspx) could be written to solve this. But given that `_timeout` value could change at any time, managing timer resets correctly is starting to feel like overkill. I think I can live with the double-check locking solution in my answer below. Seems like the the best balance of simplicity and low overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hoped to avoid a `lock` if possible, such as by composing lighter-weight constructs from [`Sysetm.Threading.Interlocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx), but I haven't come up with a good way to do that. So for now I'm doing [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which at least avoids the `lock` overhead *most* of the time.

```
private readonly object _timeoutLock = new object();

public bool CheckAndResetTimeout() {
    if (DateTime.UtcNow > _start + _timeout) {
        lock (_timeoutLock) {
            if (DateTime.UtcNow > _start + _timeout) {
                _start = DateTime.UtcNow;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lock` keyword for this:

```
static object TimerLock = new object();
static bool CheckAndResetTimeout()
{
    lock (TimerLock)
    {
        if (DateTime.UtcNow > _start + _timeout)
        {
            _start = DateTime.UtcNow;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a `lock` if possible, such as by composing constructs from `Sysetm.Threading.Interlocked`, which are much lighter weight. I haven't come up with a way to do that though.

Comment: As much as I hoped for a better answer than my own, that's the solution I went with, and since the double-check makes a huge difference in avoiding lock overhead, I marked it as accepted. +1 to you for suggesting locking though, seems fair since I did indeed use a lock. :)